# Using Masonry with ReactJS in browser

Tags: reactjs, masonry

https://github.com/eiriklv/react-masonry-mixin/blob/master/README.md

The above example shows the simple steps to get masonry-mixin working on node-js.

What solutions are available to enable my react component to use this plugin within a normal webpage? I would like a solution that has the least amount of 3rd party software to get working.

The require statement is not available without npm from what I understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Require statements can be used in client-side using a preprocessor called [Browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify).

In order to use Browserify, you have to have one main `.js` file from which all your other files are loaded via require statements (however tangentially). You then run the Browserify command to parse and bundle it all into one file:

`$ browserify main.js > bundle.js`

I've personally used `react-masonry-mixin`, and this is the approach I use (although automated with Gulp).

Comment: thanks, In the end I managed to get regular masonry working with react with a dirty hack, so will try and do it this way instead.